# android add background to action bar

Tags: android

I am using support library to add an action bar.

in res/values/styles:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

        <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme"></style>

        <style name="Theme.Transparent">
            <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Translucent</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/transparent_background</item>
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
        </style>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
        <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
               parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
            <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>

            <!-- Support library compatibility -->
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
            <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
            <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        </style>

        <!-- ActionBar styles -->
        <style name="MyActionBar"
               parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
            <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

            <!-- Support library compatibility -->
            <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        </style>

        <!-- ActionBar title text -->
        <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
               parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
            <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
        </style>

        <!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
        <style name="MyActionBarTabText"
               parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
            <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
        </style>

</resources>
```

and then when i add this

```
application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
```

to mainfest, the application falls to start. if i removed it the application works perfectly

help pelase

Comment: Maybe this link can help style your actionbar without errors http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 0):

Try using: [Action bar stylle generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). It's simple and works perfectly for default, ActionBarSherlock, Holoeverywhere themes.